# Adding a condition that would return subtracted values when going to a specific page

Tags: php, conditional-statements

How would i create a condition that would automatically return or re-add the values subtracted when moving to a specific page.

For example. I bought 3 apples, 5 is in the inventory, 3 would be automatically deducted to the inventory after pressing checkout.

However, the user cancels the order and the value made is still 2, even though the order was cancelled,

what will i do to fix that problem?

Here is my code, and this triggers when the user presses the checkout and goes to this page. Kind of automatic, but if you can fix it to a better one, more thanks. hehe.

```
// THESE CODES WILL AUTOMATICALLY DEDUCT THE QUANTITY  TO THE AVAILABLE INVENTORY WHEN GOING TO THIS PAGE.
            $qry = "UPDATE inventory 
                    SET prod_quantity = prod_quantity - $q 
                    WHERE prod_id = '$pid'";
            $result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

How do i create that condition that would return the subtracted values to the inventory?

$q is the quantity ordered by the user.
$pid is the product id.

Thank you so much. I hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 0):

After you have already subtracted the value, you have to add it back in case when the user cancels this:

```
// THESE CODES WILL AUTOMATICALLY DEDUCT THE QUANTITY  TO THE AVAILABLE INVENTORY WHEN GOING TO THIS PAGE.
            $qry = "UPDATE inventory 
                    SET prod_quantity = prod_quantity + $q 
                    WHERE prod_id = '$pid'";
            $result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

But I believe that you should only `update` the value when the order was committed. You might also want to use a [transaction](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm) and you should protect yourself against [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: Okay. That seems simple enough. However, How do i make it that, when i go to the page where subtraction happens, it only happens once, because everytime i go to that page. it keeps subtracting. How do i make it only subtract once, even if i keep returning to that page(that subtracts).

Comment: That is a task management problem. Maybe you should store your tasks somewhere and upon subtraction you should store that the task of subtraction was done.